# How to perform Pandas outer merge while completely excluding duplicated entry?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Let's say I want to outer merge 2 sets of items (data frames) with different sizes that do not have *unique enough* keys.

Set 1:

- Index: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
- Key: A, A, B, C, A
- Items: Orange, Banana, Pancake, Cookie, Oreo

Set 2:

- Index: 1, 2, 3, 4
- Key: B, C, A, Z
- Items: Out-of-stock, In-stock, Back-order, Out-of-stock

Desired result (outer merge, index order is irrelevant):

- Row 1: Out-of-stock, B, Pancake
- Row 2: In-stock, C, Cookie
- Row 3: Back-order, A, Orange

Unmatched (right_only):

- Key: A, A
- Items: Banana, Oreo

Unmatched (left_only):

- Key: Z
- Items: Out-of-stock

*Note*: The unmatched rows will be used for further merges. This is an elimination process. Later merge relaxes conditions, but at the cost of reducing accuracy.

---

**The problem:**

If I use outer merge, Pandas will find every possible combination and create duplicates (all key-A items become back-order, but I only need one, whatever that is).

If I drop a duplicate, the `drop` is performed after the `merge`, so I lost the duplicated records and they cannot be used in later merges. Technically, I can dissect the dropped records and re-add them to the data frame from an outer merge, but the performance and code logic become horrible at scale (10k+ rows, 20+ columns).

I can only use keys, not indexes as records do not follow any particular order.

For this question, the brute-force solution is essentially having 2 sets of items. Then, use a nested loop to iterate both sets, find one match, then remove the match from 2 sets to avoid duplication in the next iteration. This solution has O(N^2) runtime and is a no-go (takes 20+ hours to run).

With that said, how should I approach this issue? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure, if you had another A key in set 2, you would match it with the second occurrence of key A in set 1?

Comment: Hi. do you mind to produce a [mcve]? A sample of the 2 dfs you want to merge will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a temporary  column with `groupby.cumcount` in both dataframe to use as a merge column additional to key. Use `indicator=True` to create a column to select the three parts (both, only right, only left) later.

```
res = (
    df1.assign(cc=lambda x: x.groupby('key').cumcount())
       .merge(df2.assign(cc=lambda x: x.groupby('key').cumcount()), 
              on=['key','cc'], how='outer', indicator=True)
)
print(res)
#   key  Items_x  cc       Items_y      _merge
# 0   A   Orange   0    Back-order        both
# 1   A   Banana   1           NaN   left_only
# 2   B  Pancake   0  Out-of-stock        both
# 3   C   Cookie   0      In-stock        both
# 4   A     Oreo   2           NaN   left_only
# 5   Z      NaN   0  Out-of-stock  right_only
```

Then you can select using the _merge column depending on your case, for example

```
print(res.loc[res['_merge'].eq('both')].drop(['cc','_merge'], axis=1))
#   key  Items_x       Items_y
# 0   A   Orange    Back-order
# 2   B  Pancake  Out-of-stock
# 3   C   Cookie      In-stock
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I'm looking for. With your answer, the runtime of my script (30k+ rows in Excel) is just under 5 minutes.

Comment: @HungVu I'm a bit surprised that it is that long with 30k+, but glad it works for you :)